# jQuery treeview plugin doesn't work in my html file

Tags: jquery, html, treeview

i'm trying to make a simple website with jQuery, html and css. And i downloaded a treeview plugin which is developed with jQuery that helps me to display hierarchic view. When i downloaded the treeview plugin, it works fine in the html file that came inside the plugin's folder. But when i tried to move the codes into my own file, i doesn't works. i don't have much experience with jQuery or etc. But i will be appriciated if you point the problem. i installed my own page and treeview plugin to following addresses.

Thanks in advance.

**my html file:** http://student.cankaya.edu.tr/~c0711058/problem/urun-001.htm

**treeview plugin's directory:** http://student.cankaya.edu.tr/~c0711058/problem/jquery.treeview/

**treeview plugin's sample html file:** http://student.cankaya.edu.tr/~c0711058/problem/jquery.treeview/demo/prerendered.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the solution is not to call jQuery more than once.

Answer (score 0):

You're including treeview before including jQuery. Move jQuery to the top of your script list.

Comment: yep, there is still some problem. when i click, the elements goes down and comes up immediately :s